# Flash movie not visible in ie 6

Tags: javascript, flash, internet-explorer, embed

I have a flash movie and I use this code to embed it crossbrowser

```
'<object id="adFoxMovie" classid="clsid:d27cdb6e-ae6d-11cf-96b8-444553540000" codebase="http://download.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=9,0,0,0" width="100%" height="100%" align="left">
    <param name="bgcolor" value="#faa">
    <param name="allowScriptAccess" value="always" />
    <param name="allowFullScreen" value="false" />
    <param name="movie" value="'+this.mainSwfUrl+'" />
    <param name="flashvars" value="'+this.flashParameters+'&'+this.events+'" />
    <param name="quality" value="high" />
    <param name="wmode" value="transparent" />
    <embed name="adFoxMovie" src="'+this.mainSwfUrl+'" quality="high" width="100%" height="100%" align="left" allowScriptAccess="always" allowFullScreen="false" bgcolor="#cccccc" wmode="transparent" flashvars="'+this.flashParameters+'&'+this.events+'" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" pluginspage="http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer" />
</object>'
```

And I use this string as innerHTML for a div present on the page.

Now in all browsers except IE 6 this works fine.

The curious thing is that I have two movies and one works in this embed and the other doesn't. I can't seem to find any apparent difference. Of course the two movies have slightly different flashvars passed.

Now I've tried taking the movie link and just opening it in the browser window. The movie seems to work on its own.

PS. Can't use SWF object

Comment: the solution is not to use ie6 ^_^ (kidding). It's a bit hard to track the rest of the setup, but I recommend using [swfobject](http://learnswfobject.com/) as it makes embedding easier and it works across browsers

Comment: should I -1 this comment for suggesting SWFobject when I say I cant't use it or +1 this comment for a nice joke? I will try to come up with a small testpage.

Comment: you could write an activex control.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolution: It seems that this embed way had nothing to do with the problem.

Comment: This question didn't get an answer for a quite a long time. Anyway I hope IE6 mixed with flash is not a problem nowadays.